# A method to find the proportions within each combination of 3 categorical variables

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, missing-data, combinatorics

I have three categorical variables that describe each item, and I know how many items I have for each combination of a pair of variables. I am looking to find out exactly *how many items I have for each specific combination of the three variables*.

For example:
The variables are Colour (Red, Blue), Shape (Circle, Square), and Size (Large, Medium, Small). I know how the Shape is broken down into colours: how many red circles there are and how many blue ones, as well as the number of squares in different colours. I know the same for all other pairs of variables – Size & Shape, and Colour & Size.

Based on this existing data, how do I figure out how many items are in each Colour, Shape and Size combination? *Is it even possible to answer this question*?

Any pointers will help!

Answer (score 1):

In general it is not possible to find the individual counts without additional information. It is possible for different combinations of the 3-characteristic items to give the same 2-way summaries.

For example, here are two datasets with **X1** as either Red or Blue, **X2** as either Circle or Square, and **X3** as either Large or Medium (no small). The first dataset has 8 elements, one of each combination: RCL, RCM, RSL, etc. The second dataset only has 4 of the possible combinations, with each one repeated twice, yet it still has the same 2-way counts.

```r
dat1 <- data.frame(
  X1 = factor(c("R", "R", "R", "R", "B", "B", "B", "B")),
  X2 = factor(c("C", "C", "S", "S", "C", "C", "S", "S")),
  X3 = factor(c("L", "M", "L", "M", "L", "M", "L", "M")))
dat2 <- data.frame(
  X1 = factor(c("R", "R", "R", "R", "B", "B", "B", "B")),
  X2 = factor(c("C", "C", "S", "S", "C", "C", "S", "S")),
  X3 = factor(c("L", "L", "M", "M", "M", "M", "L", "L")))
```

```r
# One of every combination
table(dat1$X1, dat1$X2)
#>     C S
#>   B 2 2
#>   R 2 2
table(dat1$X1, dat1$X3)
#>     L M
#>   B 2 2
#>   R 2 2
table(dat1$X2, dat1$X3)
#>     L M
#>   C 2 2
#>   S 2 2

# There is no RCM, RSL, BCL, or BSM
table(dat2$X1, dat2$X2)
#>     C S
#>   B 2 2
#>   R 2 2
table(dat2$X1, dat2$X3)
#>     L M
#>   B 2 2
#>   R 2 2
table(dat2$X2, dat2$X3)
#>     L M
#>   C 2 2
#>   S 2 2
```